# fail2ban ingest IPs from AbuseIPDB

Tags: linux, fail2ban

In the same way, we report IPs for AbuseIPDB IPs, is there a way to use their DB of IPs to Ban IPS using fail2ban?

I went through this tutorial

https://www.abuseipdb.com/fail2ban.html

And it works to report IPs. But I would like to improve this process by adding the AbuseIPDB IPs to my host so I can share IPs in both ways. Is that feasible?

Thanks